# Programmatically assigning Margin and/or Padding to a Label

Tags: c#, winforms, padding, margin, tablelayoutpanel

In trying to get some labels in a TableLayoutPanel to move from the top left of their cells to the center of the cells, I'm trying to experiment with adding padding and/or margins.

However, nothing I've tried works. Here's the code I've tried and the results:

```
// Setting the padding just cuts off the bottom part of the text
//lbl.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(1);

// How to set Margin?
//lbl.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Margin(1); <- This mimics "Padding" but is not recognized
//lbl.Margin = new Thickness(6); <- This is the only example I could find, but it's for WPF
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try:

```
lbl.Margin = new Padding(1);
```

You might also want to do:

```
lbl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
lbl.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
lbl.AutoSize = false;
```

Answer (score -6):

```
labelName.Style.Add("Margin", "10px");
```

Comment: The question is about Winforms, this looks like javascript?

Comment: this answer would have been correct for a webforms app project